# Регистрация на WooCommerce (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, users

Подскажите, как сделать регистрацию обычных юзеров, которые могут переходить в свой кабинет, и отдельно регистрацию юзеров-партнеров, которые заполняют данные, эти данные отправляютcя к админу, юзер получает письмо о том, что его данные проверяются.
После подтверждения админом, юзер-партнер получает письмо с подтверждением о регистрации и может зайти в свой личный кабинет, как задать роли для юзеров (разграничить их) ?

Comment: я делал похожую задачу, реализовал разные формы регистрации и соответственно разные обработчики форм, плюс использование какого либо функционала для реализации кастомных полей в профиле пользователя где как раз и будет в маркер определяющий партнер ли это или не партнер.

Comment: каким ты плагином пользовался? и как указать роль при регистрации, это должно быть поле дополнительное?

Comment: https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/user-meta/ этим плагином,и в дополнительном поле хранил тип пользователя